# how to set the options value of facet field fixed as pretty path alias

Tags: search

I am working with `facetapi` & `facetapi_pretty_paths` for my product search.
I already created the widget ,it is showing facet in drop down list .
Now i have the problem ,that when i search any thing the first search is working fine ,but after that the widget field value is not set as of path alias .
I followed [this module](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_select) .

In the facet_select.module

```
/**
 * Widget that renders facets as dropdowns.
 */
class FacetapiSelectDropdowns extends FacetapiWidgetLinks {

  /**
   * Renders the links.
   */
  public function execute() {
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;

    $element = &$this->build[$this->facet['field alias']];
    print_r(&$this);exit;
    if(count($element) > 1){
      $options['choose'] = t('- choose -');
    }
    foreach ($element as $value => $item) {

       //here i want pretty path alias value  $options[?]

       $options[$item['#path']] = $item['#markup'];
    }
    if (end($options) !== '(-)') {
      if (!isset($form_state)) {
        $form_state = array();
      }
      $element = facetapi_selectbox_facet_form($form_state, $options, $count);
    }
  }
}
```

Is i am doing it wrong ?

Any help is most welcome .
Thank you.

EDIT:
here is the widget function

```
function facetapi_selectbox_facet_form($form_state, $options, $count = 0) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'facetapi_selectbox') .'/js/facetapi_select.js');

  $name = 'facetapi_selectbox_facet_form_' . $count;
  $form['facets'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#id' => $name,
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#options' => $options,
    //'#attributes' => array('onchange' => "top.location.href=document.getElementById('$name').options[document.getElementById('$name').selectedIndex].value"),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: That module is only available as a development release so it's not ready for product sites. Also this seems to be about a bug in the module so should be posted in the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/facetapi_select), not here. Whilst the module is Minimally maintained the last update was in February so it looks like there is still active development there.

Comment: thank you for your replay, ya i am writing another module referencing that with fixed of all the bug it is working properly ,when only one search at a time i.e, if i select any of the option  it will be redirect to the referencing link . now i want that in the submitted page  don't change the option value keep it as is because i have the option of select two option at a time.see my `EDIT`

Comment: So just to be clear is this a bug due to code in the *Facetapi Select* module or is it due to code you've written?

Comment: i am adding extra feature to it so i need this .